# LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE does not load all columns

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML file (~8MB) with the following structure:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>TALLY trumma</name>
        <categories>
            <category>Category 1</category>
            <category>Category 2</category>
            <category>Category 3</category>
        </categories>
        <SKU>44957</SKU>
        <EAN/>
        <description>Desctiption text blaha...</description>
        <model/>
        <brand>TALLY</brand>
        <gender/>
        <price>10789.00</price>
        <regularPrice>10789.00</regularPrice>
        <shippingPrice/>
        <currency>SEK</currency>
        <productUrl>http://www.example.com</productUrl>
        <graphicUrl/>
        <inStock/>
        <inStockQty/>
        <deliveryTime/>
    </product>
    <product>
    ...
    </product>
</products>
```

Now I want to load this file into a MySQL database. So I create a table using:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    name varchar (255),
    productUrl varchar (255)
    );
```

And try to load the data using:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'thefile.xml'
    INTO TABLE myTable
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<product>';
```

So the product URL is loaded into the database, but not the product name. Why is that? I have tried with several different columns but only the URL will load.

EDIT: I manage to load the `currency` and `graphicUrl` too. But no other values are transferred to the database. This is very strange?

Comment: I believe `LOAD XML INFILE` needs to be able to map XML to the columns of a given record.  Your XML has nested tags, so it might not work.  Have you thought about how MySQL would even interpret the nested tags?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't understand why there would be a difference between `<name>TALLY trumma</name>` and `<productUrl>http://www.example.com</productUrl>`? I do not want to load the nested `categories`.

Comment: You are going to need to define a table which has a column for _every_ XML tag in each `<product>` row.  As for the nested categories, MySQL might accept it or it might not.  You may have to clean up your XML file before using `LOAD XML INFILE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh I see. I did not know that I needed to transfer all the XML tags. It does not, however, answer the question that only certain tags will load. But I will try to define a column for every tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) I read: _There is no requirement that every field in the XML file be matched with a column in the corresponding table. Fields which have no corresponding columns are skipped._